# DMA on virtual address returned from ioremap

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is there any way to do DMA on virtual address returned from ioremap

Answer (score 1):

Only if the system has an [IOMMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOMMU), a memory-managment unit just for I/O (which is not common).

Since the driver supplied the physical memory address to perform that `ioremap()` call, there really should be no reason to insist on using the virtual address or calling `virt2phys()`.